# Header elment not taking 100% view port width even after setting width to 100% and 100vw

Tags: html, css

iam developing a responsive website.but the header element is not taking the full view port width on mobile devices.i checked by applying background to red on chrome emulator.on desktop header is taking full view port width.

i have already applied

```
.header {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100vw://and 100% also
 background:red
}
```

and iam using normalisation also

but all these is not working for me on mobile devices

i have created a codepen to demonstrate my problem on mobile devices?
my code pen link : https://codepen.io/sinan-m/pen/jOKRjvb?editors=1100
can you suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: You have set `height` in the code block in the question and you set `width` inside a width based media query in your codepen...

Comment: @SurajRao sorry my mistake i mean't width:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there!

If you need a full viewport width, you need to set `width: 100vw` or `width: 100%`

When I checked your CodePen, you misspelled the `margin` property inside the `@media` query.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: thankyou doston nabotov for your help,